# React router can't display multiple routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to display a sidebar with a long list of links, then when clicking on any of them, it adds a component on the right side with information about the link that was clicked.

Currently, it's only rendering ONE component at a time.

---

Here is my main render method with all of the routes.

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/">
        <IndexRoute component={App} />
        <Route path="/p/:personId" component={Person} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

I also tried this for the main render method with all of the routes.

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/p/:personId" component={Person} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

Here is my `App` component.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

And here is my `Person` component.

```
export class PersonComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.personId = this.props.params.personId
    this.person = this.props.people.find(person => person.id === this.personId)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.person.name}</h2>
        <div>
          <h5>email: {this.person.email}</h5>
          <h5>age: {this.person.age}</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    people: state.people
  }
}

const Person = connect(mapStateToProps)(PersonComponent)
export default Person
```

Comment: could you try changing your path in the `Person` route to `#/p/:personId`? you're using hash history so this might be what's missing?

Comment: `Warning: [react-router] Location "/p/58e14ffe843f7a202f500e9d" did not match any routes`

The route by itself is working properly, I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to display both routes on the page at the same time.

Comment: I dont think its the router component you would be looking at in your case. I would rather think of firing state change with onClick event handler on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass `Person` as a child component in `App`, you need following configuration

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/p/:personId" component={Person} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`IndexRoute` is needed to render default page on '/' location

Comment: Thanks! This worked for getting it rendered, but if I could ask another question - it seems to only be rendering the inner component on the first event firing and then the component doesn't get re-rendered when I click another link on the left.

Comment: Nevermind. Hadn't looked into the lifecycle methods. Needed to use `componentWillReceiveProps`.